# Ruby heredoc makes entire document a string literal in eclipse ide

Tags: ruby, eclipse, macos

I am trying to use `heredoc` to send an email in Ruby, but my entire code seems to become a string literal. I am using `Eclipse` with the Ruby plugin, and I can't figure out what the problem is. The code here is taken directly from a tutorial, so I don't understand why it isn't working. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Here is my code:

```
require 'net/smtp'

filename = "/tmp/test.txt"
# Read a file and encode it into base64 format
filecontent = File.read(filename)
encodedcontent = [filecontent].pack("m")   # base64

marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"

body = <<-EOF
This is a test email to send an attachement.
EOF

# Define the main headers.
part1 = <<-EOF
From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.net>
To: A Test User <test@todmain.com>
Subject: Sending Attachement
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=#{marker}
--#{marker}
EOF

# Define the message action
part2 = <<-EOF
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit

#{body}
--#{marker}
EOF

# Define the attachment section
part3 = <<-EOF
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"#{filename}\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{filename}"

#{encodedcontent}
--#{marker}--
EOF

mailtext = part1 + part2 + part3

# Let's put our code in safe area
begin 
  Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
     smtp.sendmail(mailtext, 'me@fromdomain.net',
                          ['test@todmain.com'])
  end
rescue Exception => e  
  print "Exception occured: " + e  
end
```

This is what it looks like in `Eclipse`:

[image]

Comment: Your code isn't the problem, as Ruby raises no errors. It's an Eclipse problem.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Well, personally, I quit using Eclipse to develop in years ago because it always seemed to want to do things its own way, and now primarily use vim on all the hosts I work on. But you probably don't want to hear that. That said, the primary task of an editor is to create text. If Eclipse is doing that, and Ruby is happy with the resulting code, and you can live with Eclipse saying things are wrong when you know they're not (because Ruby says so), then stick with it.

Comment: Well, I'm about open to anything at this point. Maybe I'll try another IDE. Aside from VIM, what else would you recommend?

Comment: Vim. :-) Seriously, it's really hard to beat it. It runs on Windows, Linux and Mac OS, plus other platforms, I use exactly the same key-presses and mouse movements on all three, and it does only what I want. Eclipse is amazing when working with Java, but Ruby/Python/Perl aren't Java and I've less than stellar results using Eclipse with those languages. Frustration convinced me to stop using it for anything besides Java. You're on Mac OS, so try MacVim, and run through the tutorial.

Comment: I love vim but the Tin Man is getting you into some serious business. A lot of people rave about [RubyMine IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) but your YMMV. There is also [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) which is a Eclipse clone for ruby and [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html).

Comment: Vim on OSes with windowing interfaces, is very mild mannered these days, because it's learned that mice are not necessarily bad. So, you can use the mouse when you want, and can slowly step into using the keyboard for your editing actions. When you learn the keyboard, then you can drop into the command-line on those OSes and be as functional as you are in a GUI version, and that is some serious business. Editing files in place at the other end of a telnet or ssh session is really handy when you're working on multiple systems.

Comment: I love, love Vim. Its the only text editor I use for anything but I just want to warn you that it will [change the way you think](http://kevinw.github.com/2010/12/15/this-is-your-brain-on-vim/) and its a [long beautiful conquest](http://www.rudism.com/s/vimcreep).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but I think that if you use tab before the closing "EOF" it should work. I think that when you add the "-" after the "<<" it looks for a tabulation before the end word, so an alternative could be deleting the "-".

I'm not super sure about it, I don't really use the heredocs because it has problems with the coding of the strings (like á é í...), but if someone is having this problem they should check that out.

I hope this helps someone.